# How to add layers to a pretrained model in PyTorch?

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch

I want to add `layer normalization` function just after `AdaptiveAvgPool2d` layer and `L2 normalization` after `fc layer`. i wanted my `fc layer`  output to be 200 so tried not to include fc layer instead of it make new `fc layer`, but it did not remove `fc layers` comes with pretrained model, i am using `googlenet`.

**my code:**

```
class GoogleNet(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(GoogleNet,self).__init__()
        self.model = googlenet_pytorch.GoogLeNet.from_pretrained('googlenet')
        
        self.fc = nn.Linear(1024,200, bias=False),
        
    def forward(self, x):
        batch_size ,_,_,_ =x.shape
        x = self.model.extract_features(x)
        x = self.model._avg_pooling(x)
        x = F.layer_norm(x,x.size[1:],elementwise_affine=False)
        x = self.fc(x)
        x = F.normalize(x, p=2, dim=1)
        return x
```

**Output I am getting:**

```
      .....  
      .....  
      .....

(aux1): InceptionAux(
      (conv): BasicConv2d(
        (conv): Conv2d(512, 128, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1), bias=False)
        (bn): BatchNorm2d(128, eps=0.001, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
      )
      (fc1): Linear(in_features=2048, out_features=1024, bias=True)
      (fc2): Linear(in_features=1024, out_features=1000, bias=True)
    )
    (aux2): InceptionAux(
      (conv): BasicConv2d(
        (conv): Conv2d(528, 128, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1), bias=False)
        (bn): BatchNorm2d(128, eps=0.001, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
      )
      (fc1): Linear(in_features=2048, out_features=1024, bias=True)
      (fc2): Linear(in_features=1024, out_features=1000, bias=True)
    )
    (avgpool): AdaptiveAvgPool2d(output_size=(1, 1))
    (dropout): Dropout(p=0.2, inplace=False)
    (fc): Linear(in_features=1024, out_features=1000, bias=True)
  )
)
```

**Output I want:**

```
  ......
  ......
  ......

  (aux1): None
  (aux2): None
  (avgpool): AdaptiveAvgPool2d(output_size=(1, 1))
  ** layer normalization here**
  (dropout): Dropout(p=0.2, inplace=False)
  (fc): Linear(in_features=1024, out_features=200, bias=False)
  **L2 normalization here**
)
```

**If someone needs to know the solution code for this problem, with the help of iacob's answer I solved it, I added it as [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67518840/14803728).**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When printing a model, PyTorch will print every layer up until it encounters an error in the `forward`, irrespective of whether the model will run (on appropriately formatted input data).

You have a number of issues in your code after loading the backbone GoogLeNet model, and hence all layers you have added after this fail to display when printed. The immediately obvious issues are:

- you must remove the `,` after `self.fc = nn.Linear(1024,200, bias=False),` or it will be interpreted as a `tuple`
- GoogLeNet has no attribute `_avg_pooling`
- `x.size` is not subscriptable. Either use a function call `x.size()[1:]` or use `x.shape[1:]`
- `F.layer_norm()` has no argument `elementwise_affine`

You need to correct these in order to get the model to run, [like so](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67518840/9067615).

Answer (score 2):

After doing corrections in code according to [@iacob](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67517149/14803728) i solved the problem.

**correct code:**

```
class GoogleNet(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(GoogleNet,self).__init__()
        self.model = googlenet_pytorch.GoogLeNet.from_pretrained('googlenet')
        self.avgpool = nn.AdaptiveAvgPool2d((1,1))
        self.layernorm = nn.LayerNorm(1024,elementwise_affine=True)
        self._fc = nn.Linear(1024,200, bias=False)
    def forward(self, x):
        batch_size ,_,_,_ =x.shape
        x = self.model.extract_features(x)
        x = self.model.avgpool(x)
        x = x.view(-1, 1024)
        x = self.layernorm(x)
        x = self._fc(x)
        x = F.normalize(x, p=2, dim=1)
        return x
```

After this i make an instance of `GoogleNet()`  and converts the layers that i do not need to Identity().

```
dep = GoogleNet()
dep.model.aux1 = Identity()
dep.model.aux2 = Identity()
dep.model.avgpool = Identity()
dep.model.dropout = Identity()
dep.model.fc = Identity()
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can just remove the last layers and then add the layers you want.

So in your case:

```py
class GoogleNet(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(GoogleNet,self).__init__()

        # load the original google net
        self.model = googlenet_pytorch.GoogLeNet.from_pretrained('googlenet')
        
        # remove the last two layers (fc and dropout)
        self.model = nn.Sequential(*list(self.model.children())[:-2])
        
        # add your dropout layer
        self.dropout = nn.Dropout(0.2, inplace=False)

        # add your dense layer
        self.fc = nn.Linear(1024, 200, bias=False)
        
    def forward(self, x):
        batch_size, _, _, _ = x.shape

        # I dont know what this does but I'll leave it here
        x = self.model.extract_features(x)
        # but I would add x = self.model(x) instead

        # insert your layer normalization
        x = F.layer_norm(x,x.size[1:],elementwise_affine=False)
        
        # put droput layer back on
        x = self.dropout(x)
        
        x = self.fc(x)

        x = F.normalize(x, p=2, dim=1)

        return x
```

But note that when you print the model summary it will not show you the normalization layers. It doesnt print the stuff you add using `F.` in `forward()`, only the initialiazions you made in `__init__()`.

Comment: `self.model.extract_features(x)` outputs the second last layer before the final classification layer.

Comment: `ModuleAttributeError: 'GoogLeNet' object has no attribute 'classifier'`

Comment: ah just without the ```.classifier```, I edited it